# Couchbase Java DCP client doesn't start the load from all bucket using Recovery File

Tags: couchbase

I'm using Couchbase DCP java client to replicate some data from Couchbase to other places. That works pretty fine when I start the data is loaded with no issues. But my bucket is pretty big now and If anything goes wrong during the execution I was restarting from the beginning and reload everything from scratch. Now this load is taking more than 3 hours.

So I started to use state files every N minutes it create a state file like with this code:

```
private def saveState(): String ={

    val filename = stateFilePath +
      s"couchbase-$bucket-${LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd_HHmmss"))}"

    val state: Array[Byte] = client.sessionState.export(StateFormat.JSON)

    // Write it to a file
    new File(stateFilePath).mkdirs()
    val output: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename))
    IOUtils.write(state, output)
    output.close()
    filename
}
```

Then I load the file and start the streaming like this:

```
client.connect().await()
client.recoverOrInitializeState(StateFormat.JSON, persistedFilePath, StreamFrom.BEGINNING, StreamTo.INFINITY).await()
client.startStreaming().await()
```

At my code I do a check if all the Vbuckets have a proper connection like this:

```
logger.info(s"Number of documents processed: $objectCount")
var vbid = 0
while (vbid < client.numPartitions) {
  val open = client.streamIsOpen(vbid.toShort)
  if (!open) {
    logger.warn("Stream is not open for vBucket: {}", vbid)
  }

  vbid += 1
```

So, for some reason when I read from the state file I start to have some vBuckets that doesn't have a connection open.
What should be the best approach?

Comment: Are you calling `client.startStreaming().await()` after `recoverOrInitializeState`? [Example usage](https://github.com/couchbase/java-dcp-client/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/StatePersistence.java#L100).

Comment: Yes I am, the streaming starts, but when it got the recover state not all vBuckets start streaming. When I check the vBucket with `client. streamIsOpen(vbid.toShort)` there are few that are not open. It doesn't happens if I start without a state file.

Comment: Three thoughts: 1) There's a lot of asynchrony in the DCP client, and the streams might not be opened immediately. If you want 10 seconds before calling `streamIsOpen` does it make any difference? 2) Is it always the same vbuckets, or are they different each time? 3) Can you post your saved state JSON?

Comment: If you enable debug logging, does anything of note appear in the log file? Wondering if you see ["Skipping partition"](https://github.com/couchbase/java-dcp-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/dcp/Client.java#L431).

Comment: @dnault I waited for few minutes and the Buckets doesn't open. I can wait for more minutes. And There are not the same buckets, usually the vBucket Ids change.

Comment: @dnault I will take a look at the Skipping Partition, Good point thanks for the detail. I will debug this process and I will let you know. Sorry for the delay of answering I wasn't able to connect to the Internet for few days :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue related to it.

The solution is working, but there is one point. If the job fails before it start to read at least 1 document in every vBucket the reload will fail for the vBuckets that are 0. The code will not start the consumers for the vBucket so you need to start manually those guys.

Although, when you read some data from all vBuckets it works perfectly.

My problem was, I was testing the failure of the DCP and the recovering. I had too much time working on this thing and I start the replication and wait if anything goes bad we were able to reload from the beginning. One good point was, the job didn't fail. And we had to reboot the machine and we restart the job all works pretty fine to recover. The vBuckets restarted and the replication is fine now.

Thanks for all comments who tried to help.